# the application is crashing when i load an image

Tags: java, android, image, load, picasso

I'm following a tutorial to load some images using **uri** and **picasso** method, it works until you select the **image** and then the application crash.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.johan.portfolijs, PID: 13364
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image:17998 flg=0x1 }} to activity {com.example.johan.portfolijs/com.example.johan.portfolijs.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.net.Uri$HierarchicalUri cannot be cast to com.squareup.picasso.Target
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4605)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4647)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:49)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1948)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7045)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:964)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.net.Uri$HierarchicalUri cannot be cast to com.squareup.picasso.Target
        at com.example.johan.portfolijs.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:87)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7759)
```

Comment: post your code here onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:87)

Comment: dat=content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image:17998

you are getting number instead of getting image name pls .. check

Comment: try this, data.getData().getPath() or  Uri selectedImageURI = data.getData()

Answer (score 0):

Here you are getting the class cast exception while assigning it to URI, so check the code again .

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
data.getData().getPath()
```

or

```
Uri selectedImageURI = data.getData()
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding this first conditional should work:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode != RESULT_CANCELED) {
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) {
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
        }
    }
}
```